# "Rev. 1:Signed by.." PDF with php/tcpdf or other language

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I managed to create self crt, and a signature (with tcpdf), but couldn't create revision "signed by"- "Rev. 1:Signed by [company_name] <[company_email]>".

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

apparently you can't create correct revision  with php, I managed accomplish the program by combining java for creating certifications and .pkx, python for gaping java/php programs, and a little of bash to create listener to a folder.

the following are guidelines for those who already understands the concept of creating a signed pdf, and need to apply signed revision:

1. [php->openssl] generate master CA, that will apply with all sub .pkx (the signed revision).
   2.[php->openssl] generate sub ca (pkx), with all sub's data(country name, locality, email, etc....) combining with the master ca.
2. [python] created a listener to the folder where you keeps the pdf's creating request (.conf) with (with the sub ca/signed revision data).
3. write your own class to create the unsigned pdf(s) saved in your own pat, also class that creates the requests.
4. apply the data in .conf on the unsigned pdf using JAVA (couldn't find any other way).

for more info: 
 - https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Req(1)

- https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Main_Page